# Draw text around circle with C++ MFC functions

Tags: c++, mfc

I have problem with text drawing around Circle.

I found great sample in C# http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30090/Text-On-A-Path-in-WPF

Bu I need to implement this in VC 6.0 and C# sample isn't working for me for that reason.

Maybe exist some basic algorithm to implement this?

All drawings must be drawn in CDC.

Comment: What isn't working for you?  Can you show some code as well as the error messages?

Comment: How do you close a question as "not a real question", when it already has a specific, useful answer?  It seems that, by definition, the question is answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDC is a thin wrapper around GDI.  GDI doesn't provide much support for what you want to do, so it will be a lot of work.  Here are a couple of approaches:

1. Draw the text normally (in a straight line) to an off-screen DIB section, and then do a pixelwise transformation to make another off-screen DIB section with the text in a circle.  Then you can blit the transformed DIB section to the output device.
2. For each character, create a logical font with the escapement and orientation set to the appropriate angle for the current position, then draw the character with that font.  Repeat for each character.  The problem here is that, even with TrueType or OpenType fonts, the rotations aren't always very good, depending on the quality of the font, hinting, etc.
3. Use a TrueType or OpenType font and get GDI to give you the vectors (line segments and bezier curves) that define the actual character shapes.  Assemble these into a straight row, and then apply a Cartesian to polar coordinate transform.  Draw the result using one of the path functions.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I tried approach number 2 and my text after rotation was "strange". Some letters was smaller and some had strange shapes.